# Adding Maven framework causes problems in project

Tags: java, maven, package

After adding Maven framework to my project everything turns **red**. A new package named **"main"** appears between packages **"src"** and the first package that I created **"java.hr.production"** (by hierarchy) as can be seen in the 1st picture. It also **changes the import address**. The 2nd picture shows maven code.
Appreciate it if you could help.
Some words are not in english so ignore those.

#1
[image]

#2
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to fix this in IDEA project settings:

Navigate

```
File-> Project Structure-> Project Settings-> Modules
```

and edit this manually

- Source Folders

  `src\main\java`
- Test Source Folders

  `src\test\java`
- Resources

  `src\main\resources`
- Test

  `src\test\resources`

see example (it's groovy, but same for java maven)

[image]

Comment: Yes thank you I took care of it that way :). Adding maven later in project completely messes up package imports.